# How to add an existing user to the Ubuntu 22.04 login interface of gdm3

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, gdm

I had created a user called "d0" ,with the cmd "sudo adduser d0".
Before do this , i had other two users.

The strange thing is that the two users I created earlier were displayed on the login interface. But the "d0" user I created cannot be seen on the login interface of gdm3. I had to click on the "Not Listed" button on the login page to proactively enter the username "d0" and it's password.

I tried switching the login page of lightdm, and the effect was the same as that of gdm3.

How can I modify the configuration file under ubuntu 22.04, to display the "d0" user on the gdm3 login page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the file to config this:

sudo vim /var/lib/AccountsService/users/d0

change SystemAccount=true  to  SystemAccount=false.
The file content after change is :

```
[User]
Language=en_US
Session=
FormatsLocale=zh_CN.UTF-8
XSession=ubuntu
Icon=/home/d0/.face
SystemAccount=false

[InputSource0]
xkb=us

[InputSource1]
ibus=libpinyin
```

Then reboot. The user d0 will show in login interface.